# Websphere portal 8 layout.html changes not reflecting

Tags: layout, websphere-portal

I have done the below steps to layout.html of my custom theme.

the default layout is :

```
<parameter name="com.ibm.portal.layout.template.href" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[dav:fs-type1/themes/customTheme/layout-templates/2ColumnEqual/]]></parameter>
```

Then i from webDav I tried to edited that particular layout.html file. I just added a class ass follow:

```
<div class="component-container wpthemeCol wpthemePrimaryContainer ibmDndColumn wpthemeLeft wpthemeCol6of12 wpthemeMedium lhs" name="ibmMainContainer"></div>
<div class="component-container wpthemeCol wpthemeSecondaryContainer ibmDndColumn wpthemeLeft wpthemeCol6of12 wpthemeMedium rhs" name="right"></div>
```

lhs & rhs are my css class which are present in theme.

Now I wont see the change when i refresh page and cross checked with firebug too.

What is see is:

```
<div class="component-container wpthemeCol wpthemePrimaryContainer ibmDndColumn wpthemeLeft wpthemeCol6of12 wpthemeMedium" name="ibmMainContainer"></div>
<div class="component-container wpthemeCol wpthemeSecondaryContainer ibmDndColumn wpthemeLeft wpthemeCol6of12 wpthemeMedium" name="right"></div>
```

I even restarted the server. Some one please point out what is wrong.

Thanks & Regards
Adeeb

Answer (score 2):

I would have expected the server restart to clear any cached layout data. Just to make sure though, try running the [refresh-page-layout task](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20WebSphere%20Portal%208%20Product%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Task_refreshpagelayout_wp8&content=pdcontent) from the ConfigEngine.

Comment: Thanks man, this worked for me. I had to tweak a little the parameters for the refresh-page-layout task (I had to not put the virtual portal parameter as I'm using the default portal), but at the end it refreshed the changes.

Answer (score 0):

same issue both with Portal 8 and Portal 8.5 .
Even if I restart server, Portal doesn't feel the changing of any layout.html file.
The only way I've found to force Portal to feel the changing is to manually **re-assign** the layout (assign a different layout, than assign back the correct layout) to each page I need with that layout.
I believe there should be another way (it would be absurd if it were forced to do so for big amount of pages), but I didn't find any solution at the moment.
Hope it can help you